# Bootstrap select error: Cannot set property '_menu' of undefined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I've implemented select box using bootstrap-select in angular 5. I've used latest version of Bootstrap select to make it work angular 5. But it throws below error.

> bootstrap-select.js:1904 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property
>   '_menu' of undefined

```
<form>
     <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
         <option>Mustard</option>
         <option>Ketchup</option>
         <option>Relish</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

[View Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LYmXkbutaM3F2uSF7Wth)

Comment: Your plunkr works fine for me?

Comment: @DrSatan1Dropdown is not working.

Comment: You'll have to provide a good deal more information, or create a plnkr that actually demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @DrSatan1 Apologies. can you check now  ?

Comment: @isherwood  I have created sample in html to show issue on plunkr. I have same issue on Angular 5

Comment: @isherwood Yes You're right. Can you check what's issue, because i have same issue in angular

Comment: @isherwood It is compatible, Check here https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/tree/v1.13.0-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap-select v1.13.0-dev is compatible with Boostrap 4. You can find Compatible bootstrap-select files here [Boostrap-select](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/releases/tag/v1.13.0-beta)

Isue is that i am not loading required jquery and popper.min.js files into project directory. Also use non minified version of bootstrap select from repository code. I've solved this issue by adding above files.

Comment: same problem with non minified version. I have bootstrap, jquery and popper. All latest versions

Comment: Did you use  Bootstrap-select v1.13.0-dev?

Comment: 1.13.18 version

Answer (score 0):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#custom-select

Your issue is that you aren't using the [select dropdown properly](https://plnkr.co/edit/bc3nzz4IX3yXN8YzdROt?p=preview) according to Bootstrap 4. You can't upgrade from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 without updating your code to use the new methodologies, unfortunately.

```
<select class="custom-select" data-live-search="true">
      <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: OP is using https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select, which requires a different class.

Comment: Oh yeah, guess you should mention that kind of stuff in your original post huh, OP

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the plugin you're using isn't compatible with Bootstrap 4. The documentation and examples all use Bootstrap 3.

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/tree/v1.13.0-dev
This version is compatible with bootstrap 4

Comment: Where in that page is Bootstrap 4 mentioned?

Comment: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/releases/tag/v1.13.0-beta
it says here it supports boostrap 4

Answer (score 0):

It works in bootstrap-select v1.13.11 with bootsrrap v4.3.1 and jQuery v3.4.1.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.11/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

I found out the problem was with bootstrap.bundle.min.js, please use the latest version instead.

Comment: @Dani Can you provide what issue is?

Comment: the same one: Cannot set property '_menu' of undefined