# Search function in select options using Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, select, bootstrap-4

When clicking on select, there are no options available.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required>
  <option value="Select Part">Select Part</option>
  <option value="Part 1" data-tokens="Part 1">Part 1</option>
  <option value="Part 2" data-tokens="Part 2">Part 2</option>
  <option value="Part 3" data-tokens="Part 3">Part 3</option>
  <option value="Part 4" data-tokens="Part 4">Part 4</option>
  <option value="Part 5" data-tokens="Part 5">Part 5</option>
  <option value="Pravesh Pariksha" data-tokens="Pravesh Pariksha">Pravesh Pariksha</option>
</select>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

When clicking on select, there are no options available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your versions:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">


<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required>
  <option value="Select Part">Select Part</option>
  <option value="Part 1" data-tokens="Part 1">Part 1</option>
  <option value="Part 2" data-tokens="Part 2">Part 2</option>
  <option value="Part 3" data-tokens="Part 3">Part 3</option>
  <option value="Part 4" data-tokens="Part 4">Part 4</option>
  <option value="Part 5" data-tokens="Part 5">Part 5</option>
  <option value="Pravesh Pariksha" data-tokens="Pravesh Pariksha">Pravesh Pariksha</option>
</select>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_menu' of undefined` in the console. [See Image](https://i.imgur.com/4zn5BYq.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014163/bootstrap-select-error-cannot-set-property-menu-of-undefined